# Why do applications update when I have declined the Google Play terms of service?

Tags: google-play-store

On my Samsung Note 3 I have declined the Google Play terms of service. Despite this, the system has connected to Google Play to download updates for all the bloatware preinstalled on the system, and a few other third-party applications such as JuiceSSH that I've installed.

**By whose authority are these updates being made, after I've explicitly denied their terms?**

Comment: Request for clarification: did you establish a Google account at all on that device – maybe for contacts, calendar, or some other part of the Google Empire's apps? If so, could their TOS be interpreted in "authority on all things Google"?

Comment: @Izzy: Yes, I do have the device linked to an account and sync contacts and calendar. However, if this is the case, then why does the device request explicit Google Play permissions at all?

Comment: I can't tell that. After all, you already confirmed the "general TOS" when configuring/creating your Google account on the device; so if there's a different agreement required, denying that should be honored (and if not, you shouldn't be asked). You could report that as a bug to Google – which is the only party to answer this question, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samsung has its own appstore: [Galaxy Apps](http://www.samsung.com/levant/apps/mobile/galaxyapps/). The bloatware on my Galaxy S6 is installed and updated through that instead of through Google Play. Could that be going on on your Note 3? I don't know if Galaxy Apps updates apps installed through Google Play, but perhaps it does.

Comment: This explanation seems likely enough to accept, until contradictory information is found. Thanks.